# Looping Through a Char Array in C Ends at a Space

Tags: arrays

This may seem like a simple question, but it has been giving me trouble for a while now. How can you loop through a char array, such as, "Hello World."? This question seems simple, but if I loop through it with with code such as...

```
for (i = 0; userPhrase[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
    if (isupper(userPhrase[i])) {
        printf("%c", userPhrase[i]);
    }
}
```

it will only print the "H" from the array and not the "W". For some reason when you loop through a char array, it only loops until a space is found and I cannot find anything about this problem. I have researched this extensively and everything says that you do it the way I have done it, but it still does not work. If someone could explain this to me, it would be a big help.

Comment: loop looks ok. how do you get the userPhrase?

Comment: Can't reproduce with `char userPhrase[] = "Hello World.";`

Comment: Suspect you mean to say `i++` not `++i`

Comment: @MikeRobinson Either `++i` or `i++` will work here.